# Email will not send to large number of people

Tags: c#

I have the following code for sending an email alert to around 60 users when an extract gets uploaded.  It will send to all the accounts if i am running it locally but when I upload it to the server it doesnt send out any emails, not unless its only to one person.  I dont have much experience with hosting and server stuff so any help you can give me would be great.

```
                if (Session["ExtractNo"].ToString() == "Extract 1")
            {

                //Connection String (SendEmail)
                string SendEmail = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sendmail"].ConnectionString;

                SqlDataReader reader;
                String SendMessage = "SELECT Name, Position, Email FROM AuthorisedStaff Where Position = 'CM' or Position = 'DHOD' or Position = 'HOD'"; //<---- change position before launch

                using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(SendEmail))
                {
                    myConnection.Open();
                    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(SendMessage, myConnection);

                    ArrayList emailArray = new ArrayList();
                    reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    var emails = new List<EmailCode>();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        emails.Add(new EmailCode
                        {
                            Email = Convert.ToString(reader["Email"]),
                            Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]),
                            Position = Convert.ToString(reader["Position"])
                        });
                    }

                    foreach (EmailCode email in emails)
                    {
                        //Email Config

                        const string username = "roll@test.ac.uk"; //account address
                        const string password = "######"; //account password

                        SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient();
                        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                        MailAddress fromaddress = new MailAddress("roll@test.ac.uk", "PTLP"); //address and from name

                        smtpclient.Host = "omavex011";  //host name for particular email address
                        smtpclient.Port = 25; //port number for particular email address

                        mail.From = fromaddress;
                        mail.To.Add(email.Email);
                        mail.Subject = ("PTLP Check");

                        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                        //change context of message below as appropriate
                        mail.Body = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(email.Name) + " <br /> <p>Part Time Payroll details are now available for checking.</p> ";

                        //smtpclient.EnableSsl = true;
                        smtpclient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                        smtpclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);

                        smtpclient.Send(mail);

                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: You are not disposing of your `SmtpClient`, maybe that is part of the problem, check for other disposeable classes too and wrap them up in `using` statements.

Comment: "it doesnt send out any emails, not unless its only to one person." -- What *does* it do? Exit without error, throw an exception, appear to be stuck in an infinite loop, etc..?

Comment: It completes the code it uploads the file and no errors displayed, just like it misses that code but when i run it locally it sends out the emails no problem.

Comment: Try to avoid creating multiple instances of SmtpClient. Rather create one instance and then use that instance to send out the mails for each iteration of "emails". Creating an SmtpClient is an expensive task and does have a hit on performance

Comment: Are the local and server environments using the same database?

Comment: Yes both using same database

Comment: Maybe server thinks your are a spammer. Try to make message body more unique.

Comment: @Draco how do i do that?  I just got that code off google.

Comment: If you add logging to the end of your foreach loop after the send, is it actually running through the code? I would suspect some sort of spam filtering as well. Maybe locally you have the ability to send to multiple people no problem because of your IP address and the email server rules. Maybe try another Email service like SendGrid and see if that helps? Just to rule out your current email server as the problem.

Comment: Are you using the same email account and setting both locally and on the server? Is it your own server or you are using shared hosting? If your server is host, then contact their technical support and they should be able to tell you what to do. Have you tried other account? Maybe only secure connection is supported? Maybe, only some email servers are accepted by some firewall. Obviously, we cannot help you much. You have to talk to the system administrator. He should know restrictions and how to setup up mail server.

Comment: @Phil1970 Yes same account locally and on server.  It is my own server and all the email addresses are my own, same domain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bulk emails will not send, c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290257/bulk-emails-will-not-send-c-sharp)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times

Comment: Is the email server yours? If so, then it would be up to you to configure it properly. Otherwise, you might have to talk to the technical support...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment this is how you would use a single SmtpClient instance:

```
        if (Session["ExtractNo"].ToString() == "Extract 1")
        {
            //Email Config
            const string username = "roll@test.ac.uk"; //account address
            const string password = "######"; //account password

            SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient();
            smtpclient.Host = "omavex011";  
            smtpclient.Port = 25; 
            smtpclient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtpclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);

            string SendEmail = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sendmail"].ConnectionString;

            SqlDataReader reader;
            String SendMessage = "SELECT Name, Position, Email FROM AuthorisedStaff Where Position = 'CM' or Position = 'DHOD' or Position = 'HOD'"; //<---- change position before launch

            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(SendEmail))
            {
               myConnection.Open();
               SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(SendMessage, myConnection);

               ArrayList emailArray = new ArrayList();
               reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

               var emails = new List<EmailCode>();

               while (reader.Read())
               {
                  emails.Add(new EmailCode { Email = Convert.ToString(reader["Email"]),
                                             Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]),
                                             Position = Convert.ToString(reader["Position"])
                                            });
                                           }

                 foreach (EmailCode email in emails)
                 {

                   MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                   MailAddress fromaddress = new MailAddress("roll@test.ac.uk", "PTLP"); //address and from name

                   mail.From = fromaddress;
                   mail.To.Add(email.Email);
                   mail.Subject = ("PTLP Check");
                   mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                   mail.Body = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(email.Name) + " <br /> <p>Part Time Payroll details are now available for checking.</p> ";
                    smtpclient.Send(mail);
              }
             }
             smtpclient.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks I am going to try this now, where you have username, password on line 7 do i need to replace these with the details?  Because in VS it says the name "username" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Do I need to add Sendmail to config file?

Comment: Ooops, sorry. I've updated the code to include the username and password in the correct place. They were defined lower down in the code which resulted in a compilation error.